# Matlab 3d plot custom function

Tags: matlab, function, plot, 3d

I am new to Matlab and i ran into this problem:
I have a function that takes 3 doubles as arguments and outputs a single double e.g.:

```
function l = myFunct(a,b,c)
    l = a^2*b^2 + (2*(c^2 - b) / (a - sqrt(c)))
end
```

Now, I need to plot the result of this function for intervals:
a = b = [0.1,3], while keeping c = 2.

I managed to do this for 2d plot of a single variable, but not for 3d...

```
R = 0:0.01:2;
fun = @(x) myFunct(0.2, x, 3);
B = arrayfun(fun,R);
plot(R, B);
```

Could you please help and explain?

Comment: I think you are looking for "surf" matlab function: see link -> https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html

Comment: The problem with that is that

    [A,B] = meshgrid(0.1:0.01:2);
    Z = myFunct(A,B,2);

Gives error using /, Matrix dimensions must agree, which is most likely because of that 2 in argument...

Comment: just create an array of the same size of A, but full of 2. The fastest way: my2rray = A*0.0+2.
Also if you prefer you can try "scatter3" (https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) but also needs a matrix of 2 in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use [`meshgrid`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), or [`ndgrid`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html), to create the two grid arrays. `A` and `B`. Then, if your function is not vectorized you need to loop over the entries of `A` and `B`. To loop over both at the same time you can use [`arrayfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html). Lastly, you can plot with [`surf`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) or [`imagesc`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html).

```
[A,B] = ndgrid(1.4:0.0001:1.44, -1:.01:3);
Z = arrayfun(@(a,b) myFunct(a,b,2), A, B);
surf(A,B,Z,'edgecolor','none')
```

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you rewrite `myFunct` as `myFunct = @(a,b,c) a.^2.*b.^2 + (2.*(c.^2 - b) ./ (a - sqrt(c))) ;`, you don't even need to use `arrayfun`, you can directly get `Z=myFunct(A,B,2)`.

Comment: @Hoki I agree. I assumed that the function was just an example, and that the actual function may not be as easy to vectorize ("If your function is not vectorized..."). If it can be vectorized it's definitely better to do so

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it with:

```
V = 2;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(0.1:0.1:3);
Z = myFunct(X,Y,X*0+V);

figure
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

Thanks all for the replies.